# Why is Buffer skipping prints on System Write API call?

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am attempting to write my own `cat` program. I want to print line by line but it appears `Write()` is skipping some characters and I don't think I have the strongest understanding so any advice would definitely be welcome.

I've placed some c++ code just to help debug, but I'm honestly having a lot of trouble with writing to these file descriptors.

Here's some of my code:

```cpp
#include <fcntl.h> // File Control Options // open(), STDOUT_FILENO
#include <unistd.h> // Access to POSIX operating system API // read(), write(), close()
#include <iostream>

const size_t BUFFERSIZE = 100;
const ssize_t FILE_DESCRIPTOR_ERROR = -1;
const size_t FILE_DESCRIPTOR_STANDARD_OUT = 1;
const size_t FILE_DESCRIPTOR_STANDARD_ERROR = 2;


ssize_t getline(size_t file_descriptor, char* buffer, size_t num_bytes_transferred) {

    size_t bytesUntilEndline = 0;
    char *pointer = buffer; 
    size_t ENDL_CHAR = 10;

    ssize_t bytesRead = read(file_descriptor, buffer, num_bytes_transferred);

    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        do {
            bytesUntilEndline++;
            std::cout << bytesUntilEndline << ": " << *pointer << std::endl;
        } while ( (size_t) *pointer++ != ENDL_CHAR);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Bytes Read: " << bytesUntilEndline << std::endl << std::endl;

    return bytesUntilEndline;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    ssize_t bytesRead;
    int counter = 0;

    if (argc == 1) {
        char message [] = "Read Failure: Please specify a filename\n";
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, sizeof(message)/ sizeof(message[0]));
        return 1;
    }

    ssize_t file_descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);


    

    while ((bytesRead = getline(file_descriptor, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) != 0 && counter < 2) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "System Call STDOUT: " << std::endl; 
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bytesRead);
        counter++;
    }
```

here's my output when I run the executable: `./myCat myCat.cpp`:

```
1: #
2: i
3: n
4: c
5: l
6: u
7: d
8: e
9:
10: <
11: f
12: c
13: n
14: t
15: l
16: .
17: h
18: >
19:
20: /
21: /
22:
23: F
24: i
25: l
26: e
27:
28: C
29: o
30: n
31: t
32: r
33: o
34: l
35:
36: O
37: p
38: t
39: i
40: o
41: n
42: s
43:
44: /
45: /
46:
47: o
48: p
49: e
50: n
51: (
52: )
53: ,
54:
55: S
56: T
57: D
58: O
59: U
60: T
61: _
62: F
63: I
64: L
65: E
66: N
67: O
68:


Bytes Read: 68


System Call STDOUT:
#include <fcntl.h> // File Control Options // open(), STDOUT_FILENO
1:
2: P
3: O
4: S
5: I
6: X
7:
8: o
9: p
10: e
11: r
12: a
13: t
14: i
15: n
16: g
17:
18: s
19: y
20: s
21: t
22: e
23: m
24:
25: A
26: P
27: I
28:
29: /
30: /
31:
32: r
33: e
34: a
35: d
36: (
37: )
38: ,
39:
40: w
41: r
42: i
43: t
44: e
45: (
46: )
47: ,
48:
49: c
50: l
51: o
52: s
53: e
54: (
55: )
56:


Bytes Read: 56


System Call STDOUT:
 POSIX operating system API // read(), write(), close()
1:
2: =
3:
4: 1
5: 0
6: 0
7: ;
8:


Bytes Read: 8
```

Comment: It looks like something in the `Read()` call is not letting me reread values that I'm trying to throw out .. i.e if I read 100 bytes the first loop and I realized that `\n` was the 50th character, the next `Read()` starts at byte 101... how could I have it resume at the 51th character?

Comment: `getline` always reads the full 100 characters. Then it returns the length of the first line, so the caller only prints that much - but the next read will start from 101st character, not from the start of the second line.

Comment: @AlejandroArmas save the unused bytes somewhere so you can reuse them the next time before reading from the file descriptor again. Or just read from the file descriptor 1 byte at a time until EOL or buffer size is reached.